# Should I use 1 or 2 hapi.js servers on the same machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, hapi.js

I have a tool I'm creating for which I have created two hapi.js api servers. ServerA contains all the small functional endpoints - currently only accepts requests from ServerB, but may not always in the future (this is why they aren't just functions sitting on ServerB). ServerB is in charge of decisioning and accepts requests from anywhere.

Is there are significant lag in having these two as separate servers on the same host? I like keeping them separate because it helps me keep the functionality separate but I also want to minimize execution time. ServerB always hits ServerA multiple times.

Should I merge the two servers or is there no harm in keeping them separate?

Comment: Why don't you create one server with separated classes ?

Comment: Yeah, that's an option. But I just realized I should probably just turn ServerA into a node module.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great scenario to look into using [hapijs plugins](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/plugins) and also [hapijs connections](https://hapijs.com/api#connections) where by you can assign plugins to use a specific connection.

Hosting multiple servers on the same box won't give you much degradation of performance except for the hop outside of process.  You are going to have trouble with setting up multiple servers listening on the same port (80).